# How To scan QR code in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am starting phonegap and I learn many plugins in phonegap but I am getting stuck when I want to use QR scanner in phonegap. Give me any solution if there is

Comment: What problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 10):

Have tried this QR code scanning in my cordova app a while back. Hope it should work fine. The code is as follows:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>QR Scanner</title>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        Click scan button to scan the QR code: <input type="button" value="scan" name = "scan" id="scan"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

function onDeviceReady() {      
     $('#scan').click( function() 
        {
          cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
              alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);            
          }, 
          function (error) {
              alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          });
        }
     );
}
```

Ensure to add jquery library js file and QR code scanner plugin from [phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) to try out this sample.

Comment: I used this you are right. but the problem is that when I using this code and run it gives me alert but i want to start camera when script run and scan something i.e QR code and print output. I think its barcodescanner or I am missing something. As you mentioned I used this all.

Comment: @AnujKumar It of course uses your device camera to scan the QR code. If you wanna extend the functionality you can do so. Not sure what is your actual funtionality

Comment: my functionality is only to when app is run it only open the camera and scan QR.

Comment: @AnujKumar Thats what this app does. It opens the camera and scans the QR code when you focus on any QR code and reads info related to the code. What else you need?

Comment: You added the jquery file in index.html. I don't have any jquery file. Is there any code in this file

Comment: @AnujKumar Its the jquery library file. Without adding this library file, you cant test the apps. download it from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js

Comment: I added the jquery file but not working. Its gives the error in console.                                                                                                       GET http://192.168.1.28:3000/js/app.js   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 7ms]

Comment: great, this is working without error. but problem is not solved its not open the device camera. when I clicked on scan button its shows the alert mean code is working but after that it ask me for input in alert i.e 'Enter barcode value (empty value will fire the error handler)'. I am creating a app only for QR scanner there is no other functionality. I am working from a week.

Comment: @AnujKumar I guess you are missing something. Nowhere in the sample code, i have coded to enter barcode value. Please recheck the sample again as i tested in device and it works fine by opening the camera and capturing QR code

Comment: hey, @Gandhi I used everything but it not works don't know what's the problem. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @AnujKumar Could you post your code in github for testing?

Comment: yeah sure. I have placed my project on github here is link: https://github.com/Anuj-786/awesome-project

Comment: @AnujKumar You have included my code sample with yours and its creating problem for you. If you look at your index.html, you have included both your qrcode.js and my app.js which will definitely cause issues. All i asked you is to create a new project, add my code alone to check the sample app which works fine in device

Comment: sorry for mixed code. now I created new repo in which i used only your code please check https://github.com/Anuj-786/QR-SCANNER

Comment: @AnujKumar This should work fine. Hope you are testing this on android device. Are you getting any error trace?

Comment: I tested it by running command >phonegap serve and i have a app in my android phone i.e phonegap developer.

Comment: I have to check it after create apk file ?

Comment: @AnujKumar You gotta generate apk by using cordova build android command to test it on device

Comment: do you used phonegap developer for testing phonegap app

Comment: @AnujKumar Nope. I dont have hands on experience on phonegap. I use vanilla cordova

Comment: ok. but its this app test the aour app on runtime. we dont want to create apk untilll our project created.

Comment: @AnujKumar I dont have any idea about what you are trying to convey. All i can say is, if you download the sample app from github and install plugin, you can test the same in device which invokes the camera and captures QR code

Comment: hey @Gandhi thanks a lot for helping me its working for after created apk. Thank you so much i am very happy now. Please come  to Dharmshala anytime.

Comment: @AnujKumar Hi anuj, glad that u r happy. Please upvote the answer if it helped. Thank u so much for de dharmashala invite.I m humbled.happy coding