# QR scanner doesnt work with phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner, phonegap-cli, phonegap-developer-app

I've started with Phonegap, I'm also using the Phonegap developer app in my iPhone to test apps, so I've tried every code sample I have found. However, none of them worked. Is there a problem when using Phonegap developer for testing barcode scanner?

This is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>qr app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <button id="startScan">Start Scan</button>
    </p>

    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my index.js:

```
var resultDiv;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
function init() {
    document.querySelector("#startScan").addEventListener("touchend", startScan, false);
    resultDiv = document.querySelector("#results");
}

function startScan() {

    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            var s = "Result: " + result.text + "<br/>" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "<br/>" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled;
            resultDiv.innerHTML = s;
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );

}
```

I do add the plugin via Phonegap `plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`, then I run `phonegap serve` and after opening it in the browser or in the Phonegap developer app nothing happens when I press the button.

Comment: Is there any console output information?

Comment: @Franc It will obviously not work in browser. Did you tested it on device? Try this out - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_QR_Scanner

Comment: @Gandhi  im testing it on the phonegap developer app, do you think thats the problem? thank you

Comment: @gumingfeng, theres not, thank you

Comment: @Gandhi ive copy the code you told me, it only sends me and alert when clicking the scan button saying "hi"

Comment: @Gandhi if i do "phonegap serve" and open it on the browser it gives me the same "hi" alert but then it opens a box, http://prntscr.com/bw9f37,  if i build the apk using phonegap build, and download that apk on my android, it only shows me the alert when clicking the "scan", please i need help :(, also i added the plugin by doing "phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner"

Comment: now im getting an error which is " scanning failed:class not found"

Comment: @Franc I build using Cordova CLI. It obviously don't work on browser as you can't scan in browser. But building it as an apk and testing it on device should have worked.

Comment: @Franc suggest you to look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983058/how-to-scan-qr-code-in-phonegap where we dealt a similar issue